# Recommended way of displaying timestamps in another locale's timezone in Workshop

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I understand that most Foundry frontend applications expect timestamps to be formatted in UTC and conveniently display these in the user's timezone.

In some cases however, time stamps should, for all users regardless of their locales, be consistently displayed in a specific time zone.

For example a flight's departure and arrival time are expected to be in the time zone of the departure and arrival locations, a factory's production event in the time zone of the factory, ...

What's the recommended way of implementing this behaviour in Workshop?

Answer (score 1):

This configuration is controlled in the property formatting at the Ontology configuration level, rather than in a particular application like Workshop.

Turn on the **Date and Time Formatting** option in the property configuration and then choose a display format. Click the dropdown that defaults to `The user's timezone` to change to `A static timezone`.

You can choose a single static timezone or choose a `Reference` to another property that has the timezone string to use. This allows, for instance, a configuration where the displayed date/time is always shown using the timezone associated with the individual object. If you are using a `Reference` the property representing the timezone values should be a `STRING` with values like `America/New_York` that match the [TZ database name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

This formatting will then be used across all representations of this property in Workshop, Quiver, or Object Explorer ensuring consistency. If you would like to have **both** representations, create a duplicate of the column in the input dataset and then have two properties on the object, identical except for the specified formatting.

[image]

Comment: NB: Unfortunately, Object Functions do not currently respect the timezone casting described here. This means that any function-based bucketing on a timestamp property will be performed in UTC. Palantir product development have been requested to enable timezone-specific bucketing.